# Msg gen error (stray '#' in program)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm building a program this message (Pose2DArray.msg):

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Pose2D[] poses
```

But when I build it, with an empty main function, I get the following errors:

```
error: stray \ in program
error: stray # in program
error: stray \ in program
error: stray # in program
(more omitted)
```

This appears to be from the following, in Pose2DArray.h:

```
return "Header header \n\

\n\ geometry_msgs/Pose2D[] poses\n\
================================================================================\n\ MSG: std_msgs/Header\n\
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.\n\
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data \n\
# in a particular coordinate frame.\n\
# \n\
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID \n\ uint32 seq\n\
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:\n\
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch\n\
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs\n\
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library\n\ time stamp\n\
#Frame this data is associated with\n\
# 0: no frame\n\
# 1: global frame\n\ string frame_id\n\ \n\
================================================================================\n\ MSG: geometry_msgs/Pose2D\n\
# This expresses a position and orientation on a 2D manifold.\n\ \n\ float64 x\n\ float64 y\n\ float64 theta\n\ ";   }
```

When I removed all that and replace it with

```
return "";
```

everything works. But since it is auto generated, the error re-appears later.

So I tried to remove the Header, so the msg was only

```
geometry_msgs/Pose2D[] poses
```

and everything works. Why can't I use Header here? Is this a bug or do I forget something?

edit: putting a comment in there ( # and some text) will also cause this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100301/msg-gen-error-(stray-%27#%27-in-program)/) by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say that you found something of a bug.  I generated your message file, and noticed that the return string generated in my Pose2DArray.h file had different line-wrapping than yours.  Logically, I assumed that this was because of the different line-ending standards (*\r\n* vs *\n*).  So then I went back to the Pose2DArray.msg file, and set emacs to save the file as a DOS file (with *\r\n*) line endings.  Regenerating the header file produced a return string with line-wrapping similar to yours.  Indeed, then #including this header file in a cpp file produced the same error you are getting.

So, I'm guessing converting the line endings of your msg file to only have *\n* will fix your problem.  I'm not 100% sure, but it is certainly worth a try.  If it does fix your problem, then a bug report should probably be filed

**EDIT**

For reference, I was using rosbuild and Fuerte for this test.

**EDIT 2**

I just tried this same test on Groovy using catkin, and was still met with this bug.  Should probably file a bug report.

**EDIT 3**

I found [this bug report](https://github.com/ros/gencpp/issues/6) in the gencpp package that mentions incorrectly formatted header strings when ending comment lines with symbols such as ")".  I added info about this line-ending problem to that report.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alpha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8726/alpha/) on 2013-11-12**:
Well it was indeed the line endings. I created the file with Notepad++ (my ROS environment is remote, I use windows to develop) which was on Windows line endings by default. Changing it to Unix/OSX format did the trick.
Glad you already added to the bug report :)